# Order of elements in multiplicative group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I found a lecture note that offhandedly states that the number of elements of order 5 in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is $4$.

I don't understand how that number was arrived at. I thought elements of order 5 were the ones that, multiplied by itself 5 times, would yield $0$ (mod $31$).

Have I completely misunderstood?

Thanks

Comment: The identity in $\mathbb{Z}_{31}$ is $1$, not $0$, so elements of order $5$ are elements such that $a^5\equiv 1\mod 31$

Comment: Ahh, of course! I see where I went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$ \left<(\mathbb Z/31)^\times\!,\times\right> \cong \left<\mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z, +\right>\,$ so we can equivalently count elements of order $\,\color{#c00}5\,$ in the latter.

$$ \color{#c00}5n\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod{30}\iff 30\mid 5n\!\!\overset{\rm cancel\ 5\!\!\!}\iff\, 6\mid n\iff n\,\equiv\, \color{#90f}0,\color{#0a0}{\pm6, \pm 12}\!\!\pmod{30}\qquad $$

Each has order dividing $\color{#c00}5$ so either $1$ or $5$. Only $\,\color{#90f}0\,$ has order $1,\,$ so the other $\,\color{#0a0}4\,$ have order $\,5$.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that $(\Bbb Z_{31})^{\times} \cong \Bbb Z_{30}$ (changing multiplication mod $31$ to addition mod $30$), so we may just as well ask how many elements of order $5$ that $\Bbb Z_{30}$ has. These are precisely those equivalence classes $[k]_{30}$ for which $\dfrac{30}{\gcd(k,30)} = 5$, in other words: $\gcd(k,30) = 6$. This is easy to check, we find that:

$[k]_{30} = [6]_{30},[12]_{30},[18]_{30},[24]_{30}$.

If we want to know which elements of $(\Bbb Z_{31})^{\times}$ these actually are, it is helpful to know the isomorphism with $\Bbb Z_{30}$, or equivalently, a generator.

$[3]_{31}$ is a generator, so one isomorphism: $\phi: \Bbb Z_{30} \to (\Bbb Z_{31})^{\times}$ is $\phi([k]_{30}) = [3^k]_{31}$, giving us the order $5$ elements:

$[16]_{31},[8]_{31},[4]_{31},[2]_{31}$

Answer (score 1):

As Moya has noted, the neutral element of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/31\mathbb Z)^\times$ is $1$. Furthermore $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $\mathbb Z/(p-1)\mathbb Z$. So in this case
$$
(\mathbb Z/31\mathbb Z)^\times \cong \mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z.
$$
The elements of order $5$ in $\mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z$ are represented by $6$, $12$, $18$ and $24$. By picking a generator of $(\mathbb Z/31\mathbb Z)^\times$, for example $3$, you get the elements of order $5$ as
$$
3^6 = 16, 3^{12} = 8, 3^{18} = 4 \text{ and } 3^{24} = 2.
$$