# Unable to understand the solution for finding the number of elements of a given order, in a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Stating the below multiplication table, modulo $31,$ in connection with the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1222575/424260).

The solutions given stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1222468/424260) for generator $3$: $
3^6 = 16, 3^{12} = 8, 3^{18} = 4 \text{ and } 3^{24} = 2,$ but failed to understand.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\overline{a} &\overline{1}&\overline{2}&\overline{3}&\overline{4}&\overline{5}
&\overline{6}&\overline{7}&\overline{8}&\overline{9}&\overline{10}&\overline{11}&\overline{12}&\overline{13}&\overline{14}&\overline{15}
&\overline{16}&\overline{17}&\overline{18}&\overline{19}&\overline{20}&\overline{21}&\overline{22}&\overline{23}&\overline{24}&\overline{25}
&\overline{26}&\overline{27}&\overline{28}&\overline{29}&\overline{30}
\\
\hline
\overline{a^2}& \overline{1}& \overline{4}&  \overline{9}&  \overline{16}& \overline{25}& \overline{36}\equiv \overline{5}&  \overline{49}\equiv \overline{18}&  \overline{64}\equiv \overline{2}& \overline{81}\equiv \overline{19}& \overline{100}\equiv \overline{7}&  \overline{121}\equiv \overline{28}&  \overline{144}\equiv \overline{20}& \overline{169}\equiv \overline{14}& \overline{196}\equiv \overline{10}&  \overline{225}\equiv \overline{8}&  \overline{256}\equiv \overline{8}& 
\overline{289}\equiv \overline{10}& \overline{324}\equiv \overline{ 14}&  \overline{361}\equiv\overline{20}&  \overline{400}\equiv \overline{28}& \overline{441}\equiv \overline{7}& \overline{484}\equiv \overline{19}&  \overline{529}\equiv \overline{2}&  \overline{576}\equiv \overline{18}& \overline{625}\equiv \overline{5}& \overline{676}\equiv \overline{25}&  \overline{729}\equiv \overline{16}&  \overline{784}\equiv \overline{9}&
 \overline{841}\equiv \overline{4}&  \overline{1}
\\ \hline
\overline{a^3}&\overline{1}& \overline{8}&  \overline{27}&  \overline{64}\equiv \overline{2}& \overline{125}\equiv((\overline{-6})\cdot \overline{5}=\overline{-30})\equiv \overline{1}& \overline{5}\cdot\overline{6}= \overline{30}&  \overline{18}\cdot \overline{7}=\overline{126}\equiv \overline{2}&  \overline{2}\cdot \overline{8}= \overline{16}& \overline{19}\cdot \overline{9}= \overline{171}\equiv \overline{16}& \overline{7}\cdot \overline{10}= \overline{70}\equiv \overline{8}&  (\overline{28}\equiv\overline{-3})\cdot \overline{11}=\overline{-33}\equiv \overline{29}&  \overline{20}\cdot \overline{12}= \overline{240}\equiv \overline{23}& \overline{14}\cdot \overline{13}= \overline{182}\equiv \overline{-4}= \overline{27}& \overline{10}\cdot \overline{14}= \overline{140}\equiv \overline{16}&  \overline{8}\cdot \overline{15}=\overline{120}\equiv \overline{-4}=\overline{27}&  \overline{8}\cdot \overline{16}= \overline{128}\equiv \overline{4}& 
\overline{10}\cdot \overline{17}= \overline{170}\equiv \overline{15}& \overline{14}\cdot \overline{18}= \overline{252}\equiv \overline{4}&  \overline{20}\cdot \overline{19}= \overline{380}\equiv \overline{8}&  \overline{28}\cdot \overline{20}= \overline{560}\equiv \overline{2}& \overline{7}\cdot \overline{21}= \overline{147}\equiv\overline{-8}= \overline{23}& \overline{19}\cdot \overline{22}\equiv \overline{(-12)}\cdot \overline{(-9)}= \overline{108}\equiv \overline{15}&  \overline{2}\cdot \overline{23}= \overline{46}\equiv \overline{15}&  \overline{18}\cdot \overline{24}\equiv \overline{(-13)}\cdot \overline{(-7)}=\overline{91} \equiv \overline{-2}=\overline{29}& \overline{5}\cdot \overline{25}\equiv \overline{5}\cdot \overline{(-6)}=\overline{-30}\equiv \overline{1}& \overline{25}\cdot \overline{26}\equiv \overline{(-6)}\cdot \overline{(-5)}= \overline{30}&  \overline{16}\cdot \overline{27}\equiv \overline{16}\cdot \overline{(-4)} = \overline{-64}\equiv \overline{-2}= \overline{29}&  \overline{-27}\equiv \overline{4}&
 \overline{-8}\equiv \overline{23}& \overline{30}\\
\hline
\overline{a^4}&\overline{1}&\overline{16}&\overline{81}\equiv 
\overline{19}&\overline{2}\cdot \overline{4}=\overline{8}& \overline{5}&(\overline{30}\equiv \overline{-1})\cdot \overline{6}=\overline{-6}&\overline{2}\cdot \overline{7}=\overline{14}& \overline{4}& \overline{16}\cdot \overline{9}= \overline{144}\equiv \overline{20}& \overline{8}\cdot \overline{10}= \overline{80}\equiv \overline{18}&  (\overline{29}\equiv \overline{-2})\cdot \overline{11}=\overline{-22} \equiv \overline{9}&  \overline{-8}\cdot \overline{12}= \overline{-3}\equiv \overline{28}& \overline{-4}\cdot \overline{13}= \overline{-52}\equiv \overline{10}& \overline{16}\cdot \overline{14}=
\overline{224}\equiv \overline{7}&  \overline{-4}\cdot \overline{15}=\overline{-60}\equiv \overline{2}& \overline{4}\cdot \overline{16}=\overline{64}\equiv \overline{2}& \overline{15}\cdot \overline{17}=
\overline{255}\equiv \overline{7}& \overline{72}\equiv \overline{10}&  \overline{8}\cdot \overline{19}= 
\overline{152}\equiv \overline{-3}& 
\overline{2}\cdot \overline{20}=\overline{40}\equiv \overline{9}&
 \overline{-8}\cdot \overline{-10}=\overline{80}\equiv \overline{18}& \overline{15}\cdot \overline{-9}=\overline{-135} \equiv \overline{-11}
& \overline{15}\cdot \overline{
-8}= \overline{-120}\equiv \overline{4}& \overline{-2}\cdot
\overline{-7}= \overline{14}& \overline{25}& \overline{-1}\cdot
\overline{-5}= \overline{5}&  \overline{-2}\cdot \overline{-4}=
\overline{8}& \overline{4}\cdot \overline{-3}= \overline{-12}\equiv \overline{19}& \overline{-8}\cdot \overline{-2}= \overline{16}&\overline{1}
\\ \hline
\overline{a^5}&\overline{1}&\overline{1}&\overline{57}\equiv 
\overline{-5}&\overline{1}& \overline{25}&\overline{-5}&\overline{5}& \overline{1}&  \overline{-6}&\overline{-6}& \overline{6}&  \overline{-36}\equiv \overline{-5}& \overline{6}&  \overline{5}& \overline{-1}& \overline{1}& \overline{-5}&  \overline{-6}&\overline{5}& \overline{-6}
& \overline{18}\cdot \overline{
-10}= \overline{6}& \overline{-11}\cdot
\overline{-9}= \overline{-6}& \overline{-1}& \overline{-5}& 
\overline{5}& \overline{6}& \overline{8}\cdot \overline{-4}\equiv \overline{-1}&\overline{-5}
&\overline{-1}&\overline{-1}
\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

***Edit:*** Have made the multiplication table below.

But, still fail to see how the second link is satisfied. Say, how $3^6=16, 3^{12}=8, \cdots.$

Have solution **only** in the above table (power table), where :
$3^6\pmod{31}
= \overline{-5}\cdot 3\equiv  \overline{-15}=  \overline{
16}.$ 
$3^7\pmod{31}\equiv \overline{16}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
= \overline{
17}.$ 
$3^8\pmod{31}\equiv \overline{17}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{20}.$ 
$3^9\pmod{31}\equiv \overline{20}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{29}.$ 
$3^{10}\pmod{31}\equiv
\overline{29}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{25}.$ 
$3^{11}\pmod{31}\equiv \overline{25}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{13}.$ 
$3^{12}\pmod{31}\equiv \overline{13}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{8}.$ 
$3^{13}\pmod{31}\equiv
\overline{8}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{24}.$ 
$3^{14}\pmod{31}\equiv
\overline{24}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{10}.$ 
$3^{15}\pmod{31}\equiv
\overline{10}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{30}.$ 
$3^{16}\pmod{31}\equiv
\overline{30}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{28}.$ 
$3^{17}\pmod{31}\equiv
\overline{28}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{22}.$ 
$3^{18}\pmod{31}\equiv
\overline{22}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{4}.$ 
$3^{19}\pmod{31}\equiv\overline{4}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{12}.$ 
$3^{20}\pmod{31}\equiv
\overline{12}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{5}.$ 
$3^{21}\pmod{31}\equiv
\overline{5}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{15}.$ 
$3^{22}\pmod{31}\equiv
\overline{15}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{14}.$ 
$3^{23}\pmod{31}\equiv\overline{14}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{11}.$ 
$3^{24}\pmod{31}\equiv\overline{11}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{2}.$ 
$3^{25}\pmod{31}\equiv\overline{2}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{6}.$ 
$3^{26}\pmod{31}\equiv\overline{6}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{18}.$ 
$3^{27}\pmod{31}\equiv\overline{18}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{23}.$ 
$3^{28}\pmod{31}\equiv\overline{23}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{7}.$ 
$3^{29}\pmod{31}\equiv\overline{7}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{21}.$ 
$3^{30}\pmod{31}\equiv\overline{21}\cdot 3\pmod{31}
=  \overline{1}.$

The set of values, of generator $3$ shows that the sub-group $\langle 3\rangle$ is a cyclic one, as all values in the set $\{1,2,3,\cdots, 30\},$ are taken once only. The values obtained are, in sequence, as given by the set of values:
$$\{3, 9, 27, 19, -5, 16, 17, 20, 29, 25, 13, 8, 24, 10, 30, 28, 22, 4, 12, 5, 15, 14, 11, 2, 6, 18, 23, 7, 21, 1\}$$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &\overline{1}&\overline{2}&\overline{3}&\overline{4}&\overline{5}
&\overline{6}&\overline{7}&\overline{8}&\overline{9}&\overline{10}&\overline{11}&\overline{12}&\overline{13}&\overline{14}&\overline{15}
&\overline{16}&\overline{17}&\overline{18}&\overline{19}&\overline{20}&\overline{21}&\overline{22}&\overline{23}&\overline{24}&\overline{25}
&\overline{26}&\overline{27}&\overline{28}&\overline{29}&\overline{30}
\\
\hline
\overline{2}& \overline{2}& \overline{4}&  \overline{6}&  \overline{8}& \overline{10}& \overline{12}& \overline{14}&  \overline{16}&  \overline{18}& \overline{20}& \overline{22}& \overline{24}&  \overline{26}&  \overline{28}& \overline{30}& \overline{1}&  \overline{3}&  \overline{5}& 
\overline{7}& \overline{9}&  \overline{11}&  \overline{13}& \overline{15}& \overline{17}&  \overline{19}&  \overline{21}& \overline{23}& \overline{25}&  \overline{27}&  \overline{29}
\\ \hline
\overline{3}&\overline{3}& \overline{6}&  \overline{9}&  \overline{12}& \overline{15}& \overline{18}& \overline{21}& \overline{24}& \overline{27}& \overline{30}& \overline{2}&  \overline{5}&  \overline{8}& \overline{11}& \overline{14}&  \overline{17}& \overline{20}& 
 \overline{23}& \overline{26}& \overline{29}&  \overline{1}& \overline{4}& \overline{7}& \overline{10}& \overline{13}&  \overline{16}& \overline{19}& \overline{22}&  \overline{25}&  \overline{28}\\
\hline
\overline{4}&\overline{4}&\overline{8}&\overline{12}&
\overline{16}&\overline{20}& \overline{24}& \overline{28}&\overline{1}&\overline{5}& \overline{9}& \overline{13}& \overline{17} & \overline{21}&  \overline{25}& \overline{29}& \overline{2}& \overline{6}& \overline{10}& \overline{14}& \overline{18}& \overline{22}& 
 \overline{26}&
 \overline{30}& \overline{3}
& \overline{7}& \overline{11}& \overline{15}& \overline{19}&
\overline{23}& \overline{27}
\\ \hline
\overline{5}&\overline{5}&\overline{10}&\overline{15}&
\overline{20}&\overline{25}& \overline{30}& \overline{4}&\overline{9}&\overline{14}& \overline{19}& \overline{24}& \overline{29} & \overline{3}&  \overline{8}& \overline{13}& \overline{18}& \overline{23}& \overline{28}& \overline{2}& \overline{7}& \overline{12}& 
 \overline{17}&
 \overline{22}& \overline{27}
& \overline{1}& \overline{6}& \overline{11}& \overline{16}&
\overline{21}& \overline{26}
\\ \hline
\vdots \\ \hline
\overline{30}&\overline{30}&\overline{29}&\overline{28}&
\overline{27}&\overline{26}& \overline{25}& \overline{24}&\overline{23}&\overline{22}& \overline{21}& \overline{20}& \overline{19} & \overline{18}&  \overline{17}& \overline{16}& \overline{15}& \overline{14}& \overline{13}& \overline{12}& \overline{11}& \overline{10}& 
 \overline{9}&
 \overline{8}& \overline{7}
& \overline{6}& \overline{5}& \overline{4}& \overline{3}&
\overline{2}& \overline{1}
\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Kindly help to understand why the power need be taken for generator elements in the multiplicative group.

***Edit #2:***
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\overline{a} &\overline{1}&\overline{2}&\overline{3}&\overline{4}&\overline{5}
&\overline{6}&\overline{7}&\overline{8}&\overline{9}&\overline{10}&\overline{11}&\overline{12}&\overline{13}&\overline{14}&\overline{15}
&\overline{16}&\overline{17}&\overline{18}&\overline{19}&\overline{20}&\overline{21}&\overline{22}&\overline{23}&\overline{24}&\overline{25}
&\overline{26}&\overline{27}&\overline{28}&\overline{29}&\overline{30}
\\
\hline
\overline{a^2}& \overline{1}& \overline{4}&  \overline{9}&  \overline{16}& \overline{25}& \overline{36}\equiv \overline{5}&  \overline{49}\equiv \overline{18}&  \overline{64}\equiv \overline{2}& \overline{81}\equiv \overline{19}& \overline{100}\equiv \overline{7}&  \overline{121}\equiv \overline{28}&  \overline{144}\equiv \overline{20}& \overline{169}\equiv \overline{14}& \overline{196}\equiv \overline{10}&  \overline{225}\equiv \overline{8}&  \overline{256}\equiv \overline{8}& 
\overline{289}\equiv \overline{10}& \overline{324}\equiv \overline{ 14}&  \overline{361}\equiv\overline{20}&  \overline{400}\equiv \overline{28}& \overline{441}\equiv \overline{7}& \overline{484}\equiv \overline{19}&  \overline{529}\equiv \overline{2}&  \overline{576}\equiv \overline{18}& \overline{625}\equiv \overline{5}& \overline{676}\equiv \overline{25}&  \overline{729}\equiv \overline{16}&  \overline{784}\equiv \overline{9}&
 \overline{841}\equiv \overline{4}&  \overline{1}
\\ \hline
\overline{a^3}&\overline{1}& \overline{8}&  \overline{27}&  \overline{64}\equiv \overline{2}& \overline{125}\equiv((\overline{-6})\cdot \overline{5}=\overline{-30})\equiv \overline{1}& \overline{5}\cdot\overline{6}= \overline{30}&  \overline{18}\cdot \overline{7}=\overline{126}\equiv \overline{2}&  \overline{2}\cdot \overline{8}= \overline{16}& \overline{19}\cdot \overline{9}= \overline{171}\equiv \overline{16}& \overline{7}\cdot \overline{10}= \overline{70}\equiv \overline{8}&  (\overline{28}\equiv\overline{-3})\cdot \overline{11}=\overline{-33}\equiv \overline{29}&  \overline{20}\cdot \overline{12}= \overline{240}\equiv \overline{23}& \overline{14}\cdot \overline{13}= \overline{182}\equiv \overline{-4}= \overline{27}& \overline{10}\cdot \overline{14}= \overline{140}\equiv \overline{16}&  \overline{8}\cdot \overline{15}=\overline{120}\equiv \overline{-4}=\overline{27}&  \overline{8}\cdot \overline{16}= \overline{128}\equiv \overline{4}& 
\overline{10}\cdot \overline{17}= \overline{170}\equiv \overline{15}& \overline{14}\cdot \overline{18}= \overline{252}\equiv \overline{4}&  \overline{20}\cdot \overline{19}= \overline{380}\equiv \overline{8}&  \overline{28}\cdot \overline{20}= \overline{560}\equiv \overline{2}& \overline{7}\cdot \overline{21}= \overline{147}\equiv\overline{-8}= \overline{23}& \overline{19}\cdot \overline{22}\equiv \overline{(-12)}\cdot \overline{(-9)}= \overline{108}\equiv \overline{15}&  \overline{2}\cdot \overline{23}= \overline{46}\equiv \overline{15}&  \overline{18}\cdot \overline{24}\equiv \overline{(-13)}\cdot \overline{(-7)}=\overline{91} \equiv \overline{-2}=\overline{29}& \overline{5}\cdot \overline{25}\equiv \overline{5}\cdot \overline{(-6)}=\overline{-30}\equiv \overline{1}& \overline{25}\cdot \overline{26}\equiv \overline{(-6)}\cdot \overline{(-5)}= \overline{30}&  \overline{16}\cdot \overline{27}\equiv \overline{16}\cdot \overline{(-4)} = \overline{-64}\equiv \overline{-2}= \overline{29}&  \overline{-27}\equiv \overline{4}&
 \overline{-8}\equiv \overline{23}& \overline{30}\\
\hline
\overline{a^4}&\overline{1}&\overline{16}&\overline{81}\equiv 
\overline{19}&\overline{2}\cdot \overline{4}=\overline{8}& \overline{5}&(\overline{30}\equiv \overline{-1})\cdot \overline{6}=\overline{-6}&\overline{2}\cdot \overline{7}=\overline{14}& \overline{4}& \overline{16}\cdot \overline{9}= \overline{144}\equiv \overline{20}& \overline{8}\cdot \overline{10}= \overline{80}\equiv \overline{18}&  (\overline{29}\equiv \overline{-2})\cdot \overline{11}=\overline{-22} \equiv \overline{9}&  \overline{-8}\cdot \overline{12}= \overline{-3}\equiv \overline{28}& \overline{-4}\cdot \overline{13}= \overline{-52}\equiv \overline{10}& \overline{16}\cdot \overline{14}=
\overline{224}\equiv \overline{7}&  \overline{-4}\cdot \overline{15}=\overline{-60}\equiv \overline{2}& \overline{4}\cdot \overline{16}=\overline{64}\equiv \overline{2}& \overline{15}\cdot \overline{17}=
\overline{255}\equiv \overline{7}& \overline{72}\equiv \overline{10}&  \overline{8}\cdot \overline{19}= 
\overline{152}\equiv \overline{-3}& 
\overline{2}\cdot \overline{20}=\overline{40}\equiv \overline{9}&
 \overline{-8}\cdot \overline{-10}=\overline{80}\equiv \overline{18}& \overline{15}\cdot \overline{-9}=\overline{-135} \equiv \overline{-11}
& \overline{15}\cdot \overline{
-8}= \overline{-120}\equiv \overline{4}& \overline{-2}\cdot
\overline{-7}= \overline{14}& \overline{25}& \overline{-1}\cdot
\overline{-5}= \overline{5}&  \overline{-2}\cdot \overline{-4}=
\overline{8}& \overline{4}\cdot \overline{-3}= \overline{-12}\equiv \overline{19}& \overline{-8}\cdot \overline{-2}= \overline{16}&\overline{1}
\\ \hline
\overline{a^5}&\overline{1}&\overline{1}&\overline{57}\equiv 
\overline{-5}&\overline{1}& \overline{25}&\overline{-5}&\overline{5}& \overline{1}&  \overline{-6}&\overline{-6}& \overline{6}&  \overline{-36}\equiv \overline{-5}& \overline{6}&  \overline{5}& \overline{-1}& \overline{1}& \overline{-5}&  \overline{-6}&\overline{5}& \overline{-6}
& \overline{18}\cdot \overline{
-10}= \overline{6}& \overline{-11}\cdot
\overline{-9}= \overline{-6}& \overline{-1}& \overline{-5}& 
\overline{5}& \overline{6}& \overline{8}\cdot \overline{-4}\equiv \overline{-1}&\overline{5}
&\overline{-1}&\overline{-1}
\\ \hline
\overline{a^6}&\overline{1}&\overline{2}&
\overline{-15}&\overline{4}& \overline{1}&\overline{1}&\overline{3}& \overline{8}&  \overline{8}&\overline{2}& \overline{4}&  \overline{2}& \overline{16}&  \overline{8}& \overline{16}& \overline{16}& \overline{8}&  \overline{16}&\overline{2}& \overline{4}
& \overline{2}& \overline{8}& \overline{8}& 
\overline{4}& \overline{1}& \overline{1}&\overline{4}
&\overline{16}&\overline{2}
&\overline{1}
\\ \hline
\overline{a^7}&\overline{1}&\overline{4}&
\overline{-14}&\overline{16}& \overline{5}&\overline{6}&\overline{21}& \overline{2}&  \overline{10}&\overline{20}& \overline{13}&  \overline{24}& \overline{-9}&  \overline{-12}& \overline{-8}& \overline{8}& \overline{12}&  \overline{9}&\overline{7}& \overline{18}
& \overline{11}& \overline{-10}& \overline{-2}& 
\overline{3}& \overline{25}& \overline{26}&\overline{-16}
&\overline{-17}&\overline{-4}
&\overline{1}
\\ \hline
\overline{a^8}&\overline{1}&\overline{8}&
\overline{-11}&\overline{2}& \overline{25}&\overline{5}&\overline{23}& \overline{16}&  \overline{-3}&\overline{14}& \overline{19}&  \overline{-5}& \overline{7}&  \overline{-13}& \overline{4}& \overline{4}& \overline{18}&  \overline{7}&\overline{9}& \overline{19}
& \overline{14}& \overline{-3}& \overline{-15}& 
\overline{10}& \overline{5}& \overline{25}&\overline{2}
&\overline{20}&\overline{8}
&\overline{-1}
\\ \hline
\overline{a^9}&\overline{1}&\overline{16}&
\overline{-2}&\overline{8}& \overline{1}&\overline{-1}&\overline{6}& \overline{4}&  \overline{4}&\overline{16}& \overline{-8}&  \overline{2}& \overline{-2}&  \overline{-4}& \overline{-2}& \overline{2}& \overline{-4}&  \overline{-2}&\overline{16}& \overline{8}
& \overline{7}& \overline{-4}& \overline{-4}& 
\overline{-8}& \overline{1}& \overline{1}&\overline{-8}
&\overline{2}&\overline{15}
&\overline{1}
\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: This is not a multiplication table but a table of the first powers  of each element. You need only the column of $\bar a=\bar3,$ but you need to complete it. E.g. $\bar3^6=\bar3\cdot(\overline{-5})=\overline{-15}=\overline{16}.$ Also, note these are equalities, not congruences (either write $m\equiv n,$ or $\bar m=\bar n$).

Comment: I admire your effort, @jiten, but you’re way off. You need to return to the basics. Like Anne said: that is *not* a multiplication table.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Request to put an answer; as failed to grasp the logic still. Please vet:  So, power table is needed, not the multiplication table.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Am not clear, where I showed that " $g=\overline{3}$ has order $30$ and hence is a generator of this group." Do you mean by that, the last entry of the multiplication table? But, then is the modulo $31$ being prime, not enough?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Please tell will the powers of any generator, like the chosen $\overline{3},$ achieves the same result. Hence, any of the $30$ generators is enough.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Panick is natural, but was the earlier question similar? Also, $(3,30)\ne 1,$ so that cannot be a criteria for choosing $3.$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Request some reference source, for your last comment.

Comment: Kindly vet the edited OP.